# Getting object property value in non public members

Tags: c#, reflection

In my cookie collection, I need to retrieve this value and I realize that I can use reflection to do it. After seeking some references from Google, I keep getting `null` from my code. Anyone know where's my problem?

```
var cookielist = 
allCookies.GetType().GetField("m_list[0]", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

[image]

Comment: I think you don't even need to use reflection, just use `allCookies[0]`to get the first element instead of trying to analyze the internal implementation of the `CookieCollection`. Or even better `allCookies["aps03"]` to get the element with the given name (since the index may change)

Comment: Thank you! Still wondering why I have to make it complicated.><

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do `GetField("m_list[0]", ...)` as the field `m_list[0]` does not exist. Instead you should get the whole list `GetField("m_list", ...)`, cast it to arrayList and then get the first element.